# HTTP request may return objects of two structures

Tags: java, json

HTTP request may return objects of two structures. It is a structure when returning success, and another structure when returning failure. I can't get the sign of success or failure. I can only receive the following structure. How do i parse with java?

```
SuccessResponse:
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"lulu"
    "score":[100,97,89]
}

ErrorResponse:
{
    "errorCode": "string",
    "errorMessage": "string"
}
```

Comment: Well i guess Create a DTO with all the fields: [id, name, score, errorCode, errorMessage] Then when you receive the request just check for field specific to success/failure and process accordingly.

Comment: The response is clearly in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).  Your best bet for parsing in Java ... is to find a JSON library.  [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) is one good choice.  [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) is another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's JSON - and most libraries for working with JSON will support this in one way or another:

-> If you parse the return to a simple Map<>, you can check if there's a key "errorCode" in the Map

-> If you parse to object, you can spefify all fields in your response object and allow null values for id and score. Then again you can simply `if(obj.errorCode != null)`

In Jackson it might look like this

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
 public class MyReturn {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    List<Integer> score;
    String errorCode;
    String errorMessage;
 }
```

plus getters and setters for each...